# Docker image for ruby 2.6.1

Tags: ruby, docker, ruby-2.6

It seems like the latest 2.6.1 version is not yet available at [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby)

I defined it as follows in `Dockerfile` and it fails to pull it:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.1
```

The [official repo](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/tree/master/2.6/stretch) for Docker ruby image was updated just 2 days ago to 2.6.1.
Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/ruby#see-a-change-merged-here-that-doesnt-show-up-on-docker-hub-yet

Comment: Just check available images at https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby and you will not find 2.6.1 there.

Comment: That is why I linked to the documentation explaining exactly that.

Comment: Exactly, the [PR 5382](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/5382) that will update docker image for Ruby 2.6.1 release is still open.

Comment: Good, then it sounds like you have your answer.

Comment: Yep, it was updated just 6 hours ago. I hope they'll publish it in some days or so.

Comment: It's done, the official image for `2.6.1` is [available](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/6301325faf42a96b1fd1be5650e451cae31e0728/2.6/stretch/Dockerfile) now!

Comment: Bitnami docker ruby 2.6 [hear](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-ruby/tree/master/2.6-prod) `2.6`

Answer (score 0):

You can get old ruby image form **PPC64le**.

https://hub.docker.com/r/ppc64le/ruby/tags?page=1

**PPC64** explain that in this article.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ppc64